# Property [columns] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i'm getting this error while trying to add a subquery select to a query builder. this error occurs when i try to get the product count for a given category.

**addSubSelect Macro**

```
Builder::macro('addSubSelect', function ($column, $query) {
            if (is_null($this->columns)) {
                $this->select($this->from.'.*');
            }
            return $this->selectSub($query, $column);
        });
```

**Category.php**

```
public function scopeWithProductCount($query){
        $query->addSubSelect('products_count', function($query) {
            $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
            $query->select('id')
                ->from('products')
                ->whereColumn('category_id', 'category.id')
                ->count();
        });
        });
    }
```

**Category Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = $this->user()->store->categories()
            ->withProductsSum()
            ->get();

        return response()->json($categories);
    }
```

[image: here is a screenshot of the error]

**i changed the scopedWithProductCount method to this to try and get more debugging options but i end up with the same error**

```
public function scopeWithProductCount($query){

    $query->addSubSelect('', function($query) {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `columns` property is in the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` Class and not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Your `$this` will refer to the `Eloquent\Builder` reference and not the `Query\Builder`.

So try changing your `macro` like this:

**addSubSelect Macro**

```
Builder::macro('addSubSelect', function ($column, $query) {
    if (is_null($this->getQuery()->columns)) {
            $this->select($this->from.'.*');
    }
    return $this->selectSub($query, $column);
});
```

Comment: This worked... Thanks loads... I was referring to to `Eloquent \Builder` instead of the `Query\Builder`

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Write join and the name of the table before the field:

```
public function scopeWithProductCount($query){
        $query->addSubSelect('products_count', function($query) {
            $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
            $query->select('products.id')
                ->from('products')
                ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
                ->count();
        });
    });
}
```